How to get position of a rectangle which I draw using Custom Paint in flutter
I am creating a waste management app where user can take image then this Image is shown in a screen where user can draw rectangles around trash. I am using Stack with Custom Paints for doing this. But I am not able to get position of rectangles because this image is then to be sent to a ML model for further evolution. I am using GetX
Here is my code snippet:
body: SizedBox(
        width: double.maxFinite,
        child: GetBuilder(builder: (DetectTrashController controller) {
          return Stack(
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                onPanStart: (details) {
                  controller.startDrawing(details.localPosition);
                },
                onPanUpdate: (details) {
                  controller.updateDrawing(details.localPosition);
                },
                onPanEnd: (details) {
                  controller.endDrawing();
                },
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Image.file(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      height: double.maxFinite,
                      width: double.maxFinite,
                      File(controller.imagePath!),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: controller.image!.height.toDouble(),
                      width: controller.image!.width.toDouble(),
                      child: CustomPaint(
                        key: controller.widgetKey,
                        painter: RectanglePainter(
                          controller.rectangles,
                          controller.currentRect,
                          controller.image!,
                        ),
                        size: Size.infinite,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            controller.toggleDrawing();
                          },
                          child: Container(
                              height: 31.v,
                              width: 161.h,
                              color: whiteColor,
                              child: Obx(
                                () => Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                  children: [
                                    Checkbox(
                                      checkColor: whiteColor,
                                      fillColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                                          controller.drawingEnabled.value
                                              ? Colors.black
                                              : null),
                                      shape: controller.drawingEnabled.value
                                          ? const CircleBorder()
                                          : null,
                                      value: controller.drawingEnabled.value,
                                      onChanged: (value) {
                                        controller.toggleDrawing();
                                      },
                                    ),
                                    Text(controller.drawingEnabled.value
                                        ? "Cancel Selection"
                                        : "Draw Selection"),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.v),
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: CustomElevetedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    backgroundColor: primaryColor,
                    child: "Update",
                    size: Size(189.h, 40.v),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        }),
      ),

CustomPaint Class
class RectanglePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final List<Rectangle> rectangles;
  final Rect? currentRect;
  

  RectanglePainter(this.rectangles, this.currentRect,);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.red
      ..strokeWidth = 2
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
  

    // Draw existing rectangles
    for (var rectangle in rectangles) {
      canvas.drawRect(rectangle.rect, paint);
    }

    // Draw the current rectangle being dragged
    if (currentRect != null) {
      canvas.drawRect(currentRect!, paint);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true; // Repaint every time to reflect changes
  }
}

OutPut
Output

The Rect class has various properties for getting positions on the rectangle. For example you can call .center to get the position in the center of the rectangle.

yes exactly. But I want position of the whole rectangle(widget) on a screen

You can call .topLeft and .bottomRight to get the bounds of the rectangle.
